# NEO4J: Is it possible to use regular expressions in Relationshiptypes with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

is it possible to use regex in relationshiptypes. In some cases my application generates dynamically RelTyps. So when it comes to execute a cyhper query, the application only knows a specific part of the relationshiptyp. Because of this I want to use a regex for the rest of the relationship. Here is an example for a possible dynamic relationshiptyp:

```
(node)-[:`http://www.examplerelation.com/type/number/test[1]`]->(otherNode)
```

I want to replace the number in "`text[]`" with a regular expression. 
The other question is, would it be better to save this number as a property in the relationship?

Thanks for your help!
Greetings Max :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not misuse the relationship type to store data. This can also lead to serious performance problems. Store the data in a property of the relationship.

You will also run into issues with the 32k relationship type limit ([link](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/capabilities-capacity.html#capabilities-data)).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Issue solved. I saved the number as a property in the relationship. But it's still interesting if regex are possible in cypher queries.

Comment: You can use Apache lucene on an index, that's as close as it gets atm. Lucene is pretty powerful though.